# Error:Unknown host 'maven.fabric.io'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter, crashlytics-android

I am trying to use the fabric io plugin and have to use the below maven repo :

maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

but it gives me error while syncing : 
Error:Unknown host 'maven.fabric.io'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

I have checked my proxy connection by putting below URL in the Check connection > Check Proxy Connection Box

```
http://maven.fabric.io
```

and

```
http://maven.fabric.io
```

What else am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that `maven.fabric.io` is included in some adblockers lists.

If you have an AdBlocker directly on your modem you might want to add this domain to your whitelist. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: For me, this was the solution. I ran my VPN connection to bypass my routers Adblock and voila it worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: My case was resolved by changing the IP and using the VPN. Because firebase.google.com did not load for me. The problem was solved when the website loaded for me and I rebuilt it .

Answer (score 2):

"invalidate Caches/restart" works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your app level build.gradle has these lines.

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

And project leve build.gradle must have these line

```
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }
}
```

Comment: why maven has different urls at app and Project level?

Answer (score 0):

`invalidate Caches/restart` did not work for me and I already had fabric maven and plugin in my `build.gradle`. I had to connect to a different proxy for this to work. Probably it was being blocked as @jjacobi pointed out.